# When is the pegged price equal to the market price

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, financial-economics, financial-crises

Suppose the government pegs an exhaustible resource, at a price $P^*$. I found out that the shadow price (initial price of the resource if government didn't peg) would be 
$$Q_t = ( \sigma i S_t )^\frac{-1}{\sigma}$$.

Where $S_t$ is the resources left after time $t$. And  $\sigma$ is a parameter, whereas $i$ is the interest rate.

I'm trying to show that if $q(t) = ln Q_t$ and $ \triangle q(t) = i$ (change in q(t)) Then

$$Q_t = P^*$$

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to show? What is $P^*$? Does it change at every $t$ given you have $Q_t$?

Comment: What does this has to do with financial economics? Are you sure those tags are correct? Maybe natural resources?

Comment: @luchonacho, first thing flashed in my mind was Hotelling rule when I read the question, but a google search gave links to the applications of the concept in finance literature. I was going to edit the tags otherwise.